# How to visualize Barchart using ggplotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, bar-chart

My df has two numerical variables and categorical columns. Negative Bars are in white white with the same coloured shape/boundaries as corresponding positive bars. Now I want to set one colour for every bars (e.g blue) and have only B categories in different color (e.g Red) and do all these in `ggplotly()` in order to get interactive chart

```
df <- data.frame(model  = c("A","B","C","D","B","C"),
                  category = c("origin", "origin","origin","abroad","abroad","abroad"),
                 pos = c(40,50,45,100,105,80),
                 neg = c(-10,-5,-4,-16,-7,-2),
                 Colour = c("chocolate","deeppink4","yellow","steelblue3","deeppink4","yellow"))

Colour <- as.character(df$Colour)
Colour <- c(Colour,"white")
names(Colour) <- c(as.character(df$model),"white")



df <- df %>% pivot_longer(., cols=c('pos','neg'),
                           names_to = 'sign') %>% 
  mutate(Groups = paste(category, model),
         sign = factor(sign, levels = c("neg", "pos")))

ggplot() +
  # plot positive with fill and colour based on model
  geom_col(aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(model, value, category),
               fill = model, color = model), 
           data = df[df$sign == "pos", ],
           position = "stack") +
  # plot negative with colour from based on model, but fill fixed as "white"
  geom_col(aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(model, value, category),
               color = model), 
           data = df[df$sign == "neg", ], 
           fill = "white",
           position = "stack") +
  # the rest is same as OP's code
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  labs(fill = "model") +
  facet_grid(category ~ ., switch = "y",scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  labs( title = "BarPlot",
        subtitle = "changes",
        y = " ")
```

[image]

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: I need to set  A D C the same colours and only B need to be different. (without specifying colors manually in df)

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted to color them the same, which is just the border. Did you mean color, fill, or both?

I changed the fill and color in one layer (the positive layer). This shows you one of many possible methods that you could use to accomplish the uniform color or fill in all but one category.

This way if you wanted only color, only fill, or both you will have enough information to modify it as you see fit.  The important part is that when you pick a color, you do this outside of `aes`.

```
ggplot() +
  # plot positive with fill and colour based on model
  geom_col(aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(model, value, category),
               fill = model, color = model), 
           color = ifelse(df[df$sign == "pos", ]$model == "B",
                         "red", "blue"),
           fill = ifelse(df[df$sign == "pos", ]$model == "B",
                          "red", "blue"),
           data = df[df$sign == "pos", ],
           position = "stack") +
  # plot negative with colour from based on model, but fill fixed as "white"
  geom_col(aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(model, value, category),
               color = model), 
           data = df[df$sign == "neg", ], 
           fill = "white",
           position = "stack") +
  # the rest is same as OP's code
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  labs(fill = "model") +
  facet_grid(category ~ ., switch = "y",scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines")) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") + 
  labs( title = "BarPlot",
        subtitle = "changes",
        y = " ") -> plt

ggplotly(plt)
```

[image]

Comment: negative bars must have the same coloured borders as their positive ones

Comment: As I said in my answer, you wrote you wanted a uniform color, but I wasn't sure if you meant the literal parameter `color`, `fill`, or both, so I showed how to do both in my answer. Are you saying now that you want the fill of one trace and the color of both traces to be the same color scheme that I showed in my answer for the first trace?